# Extjs cannot load data from server side using load() method

Tags: ajax, servlets, extjs

when i select a menu, i hope Extjs can load the data from the servlet.   I debugged and the correct data should be passed to the script, but it doesn't work.   I am attaching all related codes in this post.  Please help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="author" content="Yeeku.H.Lee(CrazyIt.org)" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title> Using Ext.form.action.Load to load data </title>
 <!-- impot Ext JS CSS -->
 <link href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <!-- import Ext JS JavaScript lib -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js">
 </script>
 <!-- import Ext JS JavaScript language -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-lang-zh_CN.js">
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function(){
 var itemHandler = function(item, e)
 {
  Ext.getCmp('bookForm').load(
  {
   params: {
    bookId: item.value
   },
   
   failure: function(form, action)
   {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Load Failure', action.result 
     ? action.result.msg : "The server has problem");
   }
  });
 }
 
 Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  id:'bookForm',
  title: 'Using Ext.form.action.Load to load Form data',
  bodyPadding: 5,
  width: 350,  
  url: '/AjaxBookExtjs/getBook',
  method: 'POST', 
  layout: 'anchor',
  defaults: {
   anchor: '100%'
  },
  defaultType: 'textfield',
  fieldDefaults: {
   labelAlign: 'left',
   labelWidth: 100
  },
  items: [
   {
    fieldLabel: 'Book Name',
    name: 'name', 
    readOnly: true, 
   },
   {
    fieldLabel: 'Author', 
    name: 'author',
    readOnly: true, 
   },
   {
    fieldLabel: 'Price', 
    name: 'price', 
    readOnly: true, 
   }
  ],
  bbar: [
   {xtype: 'tbfill'},
   {
    text: "Select Book",
    xtype: 'splitbutton',
    width: 100,
    menu: [ 
     {text:'Book1' , value:1 , handler: itemHandler},
     {text:'Book2' , value:2 , handler: itemHandler},
     {text:'Book3' , value:3 , handler: itemHandler},
     {text:'Book4' , value:4 , handler: itemHandler}
    ]
   }
  ],
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
package org.crazyit.extjs.service;

import org.crazyit.extjs.domain.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BookService
{
 static Map<Category , List<Book>> bookDb = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 static
 {
  List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
  books.add(new Book(1, "Book 101" ,"Li Gang" ,109));
  books.add(new Book(2, "Book 102" ,"Li Gang" ,89));
  books.add(new Book(3, "Book 103" ,"Li Gang" ,69));
  bookDb.put(new Category(1 , "IT Books") , books);
  books = new ArrayList<Book>();
  books.add(new Book(4, "Book 201" ,"AAA" ,21));
  books.add(new Book(5, "Book 202" ,"BBB" ,18));
  bookDb.put(new Category(2 , "Novel") , books);
  books = new ArrayList<Book>();
  books.add(new Book(6, "Book 301" ,"CCC" ,22));
  books.add(new Book(7, "Book 302" ,"DDD" ,14));
  bookDb.put(new Category(3 , "Research") , books);
 }
 public Book getBookById(int id)
 {
  for(List<Book> books : bookDb.values())
  {
   for(Book book : books)
   {
    if(book.getId() == id)
    {
     return book;
    }
   }
  }
  return null;
 }

 public List<Book> getAllBooks()
 {
  List<Book> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for(List<Book> books : bookDb.values())
  {
   result.addAll(books);
  }
  return result;
 }

 public List<Book> getBooksByPage(int start , int page , int limit)
 {
  List<Book> allBooks = getAllBooks();
  int toIndex = page * limit < allBooks.size() ? page * limit : allBooks.size();
  return allBooks.subList(start , toIndex);
 }

 public List<Book> getBooksByPrefix(String prefix)
 {
  List<Book> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for(List<Book> books : bookDb.values())
  {
   for (Book book : books )
   {
    if(book.getName().startsWith(prefix))
    {
     result.add(book);
    }
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 public int getBookCount()
 {
  return getAllBooks().size();
 }

 public Set<Category> getAllCategorys()
 {
  return bookDb.keySet();
 }

 public List<Book> getBooksByCategory(int categoryId)
 {
  for(Category category : bookDb.keySet())
  {
   if(category.getId() == categoryId)
   {
    return bookDb.get(category);
   }
  }
  return null;
 }
}
```

```js
package org.crazyit.extjs.domain;


public class Book
{
 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private String author;
 private double price;

 public Book()
 {
 }

 public Book(Integer id , String name , String author , double price)
 {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.author = author;
  this.price = price;
 }


 public void setId(Integer id)
 {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public Integer getId()
 {
  return this.id;
 }


 public void setName(String name)
 {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public String getName()
 {
  return this.name;
 }


 public void setAuthor(String author)
 {
  this.author = author;
 }
 public String getAuthor()
 {
  return this.author;
 }


 public void setPrice(double price)
 {
  this.price = price;
 }
 public double getPrice()
 {
  return this.price;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
  return "Book[name=" + name+ "]";
 }
}
```

```js
package org.crazyit.extjs.web;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.json.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.crazyit.extjs.service.*;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/getBook")
public class GetBookServlet extends HttpServlet
{
 public void service(HttpServletRequest request ,
  HttpServletResponse response)
  throws IOException , ServletException
 {
  
  request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
  String bookId = request.getParameter("bookId");
  Map<String , Object> result = new HashMap<>();
  result.put("success" , true);
  result.put("data" , new BookService().getBookById(Integer.parseInt(bookId)));
  response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.print(new JSONObject(result));
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: Share your store config please

Comment: @FrancisDucharme  Thanks Francis. I didn't get any error message.

Comment: @mindparse  which config file do you mean?